# Can Game Center keep a match running after quit?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm thinking that I will try to do this with Game Center. The idea is to make a match for a game of exactly two players, which compete in "real time", but not strictly real time. By this I mean that the match may continue even if one or both of the players quit the app. Is it possible to keep the match running on the Game Center server even though the clients close?

The central objective is to keep a timer running (and when a player resumes the game and wins, a notification is made), so I'm not sure if the server would allow that. Can a match keep on running even though the players quit the app?

Comment: Does the match have to continue? Just let the match end and continue the game on the device which is still playing.

Comment: @68cherries But what happens if both players quit, but the timer is meant to keep running?

Comment: Edited -  I think I see what you mean, and I'm pretty sure the answer is no. You can't keep a match going after a player has quit.

Comment: @68cherries The timer keeps track of the length of the match since it began. A player wins whenever he reaches the objective before the opponent and both players should know almost exactly when there is a winner. The timer server-side would make it more difficult to create discrepancies.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you want the game to continue after one player quits. Shouldn't that be called a draw? Or the other player's victory?

Comment: The player that's left may have to continue to a specific point or achieve an objective -- there's not necessarily an automatic win (or even a draw) if the other player quits.

Comment: @68cherries Even both player may quit (quit according to the server), but the game goes on until either 1) the timer reaches a limit, say 20 minutes, or 2) a player logs back in to the game and finishes it.

Comment: Has someone tried this before?